# Retrieving the Legal prose attached with a contract

Tags: corda

How the legal prose attached with contract can be retrieved from the receiving node side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have attached a file to a transaction that you want to open on the side of the receiving node, you can use the following code:

```
val ids: List<AttachmentId> = serviceHub.attachments.queryAttachments(
  AttachmentQueryCriteria.AttachmentsQueryCriteria(
    filenameCondition = Builder.equal("some name")
  )
)
val attachments: List<Attachment?> = ids.map { id -> serviceHub.attachments.openAttachment(id) }
```

Comment: I added the Legal prose using annotation rather than transaction attachment @LegalProseReference(uri = "http://sample.com/test.html")
public class IOUContract implements Contract { }

Comment: that is just related to documentation ```* All code contracts should include a ``LegalProseReference`` link to the legal document describing the contract's intended behavior```

Comment: thanks @dan-newton for your reply.....please clarify the AttachmentId in list<>  and "some name" mentioned in Buider.equal()

Comment: `"some name"` is just a placeholder for whatever vault you want to query.

Comment: which means we have to manually specify the file name. How we can can automatically read the transaction attachment hash from receiving nodes RPC client @dan-newton